# PEGASUS From pytorch to tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I have fine-tuned PEGASUS model for abstractive  summarization using [this script](https://gist.github.com/jiahao87/50cec29725824da7ff6dd9314b53c4b3) which uses huggingface.
The output model is in pytorch.

Is there a way to transorm it into tensorflow model so I can use it in a javascript backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways in which you can potentially achieve a conversion, some of which might not even need Tensorflow at all.

Firstly, the way that does what you intend to do: PEGASUS seems to be completely based on the `BartForConditionalGeneration` model, according to the [transformer implementation notes](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/pegasus.html#implementation-notes). This is important, because there exists a script to convert [PyTorch checkpoints to TF2 checkpoints](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/convert_pytorch_checkpoint_to_tf2.py). While this script does not *explicitly* allow you to convert a PEGASUS model, it does have options available for BART. Running it with the respective parameters should give you the desired output.

Alternatively, you can potentially achieve the same by exporting the model into the ONNX format, which also has [JS deployment options](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxjs). Specific details for how to convert a Huggingface model to ONNX can be found [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/serialization.html).

Comment: I tried the ONNX command which is in the huggingface document but I keep getting the following message: '/bin/bash: pt,: No such file or directory' Note: I ran the command on colab and checkpoint-4000 is the folder which has the model and all its related files